# content search webpart query string filter with multiple values

Tags: content-search-web-part

I'm using a standard content search webpart. In my query I have a query string filter on a field called HRPortalRole. The column that links to the HRPortalRole managed property is a choice column. The querystring filter in the query looks like this.

```
HRPortalRole:{QueryString.role}
```

If I specify only one value in the query string it is working correct. (sample below)

```
?role=employee
```

What I want to do is specify more than one role, so that I can show content of both roles. For example something like this

```
?role=employee&role=manager
```

or something like this

```
?role=employee;manager
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: The most I found was something similar to an expansion operator, using a pipe: `{|HRPortalRole:{QueryString.role}}` but I haven't figured out how to format the querystring, I would think it would be `?role=foo&role=bar`, but no dice.  https://www.itunity.com/article/sharepoint-query-variables-295